# Expand date column for a given range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

Looking for an elegant solution where I can expand the dates (past dates and future dates) from my df and maintaining some values.

Having a df like this, note that dates can be duplicated.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'player_id':[1,1,1,1,1],'field_id':[2,2,2,2],'date':['01-01-2021','05-01-2021','09-01-2021','12-12-2021','01-01-2021'],'score':[1,0,2,4,3]})

'|    |   player_id |   field_id | date       |   score |
 |---:|------------:|-----------:|:-----------|--------:|
 |  0 |           1 |          2 | 01-01-2021 |       1 |
 |  1 |           1 |          2 | 05-01-2021 |       0 |
 |  2 |           1 |          2 | 09-01-2021 |       2 |
 |  3 |           1 |          2 | 12-12-2021 |       4 |'
```

I can get almost what I want with

```
data.set_index(data.date).sort_index().asfreq('D')
```

But I have the following problems

- All columns in the df go na (sum['score']) returns 0 when should be 7).
- I would like to add past and future dates out of the scope of the dataframe (from 2015 til 2025 for example).
- All columns values but score and date should be copied when expanding.

The expected output would be something like

```
'|    |   player_id |   field_id | date       |   score |
 |---:|------------:|-----------:|:-----------|--------:|
 |  0 |           1 |          2 | 01-01-2015 |       0 | #first date range I pick
                       ....  
 |  1 |           1 |          2 | 01-01-2021 |       1 |
 |  2 |           1 |          2 | 05-01-2021 |       0 |
 |  3 |           1 |          2 | 09-01-2021 |       2 |
 |  4 |           1 |          2 | 12-12-2021 |       4 |
                       ....
 |  0 |           1 |          2 | 12-31-2025 |       0 |' #last date range I pick
```

Comment: Could you have a look at your data again. When i run your code It gives `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Comment: What do you mean by `All columns values but score and date should be copied when expanding.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have data for the other columns. To get daterange you can use this:

```
pd.date_range(start='01-01-2015', end='12-31-2025')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html